# Migrating Scopes from Rails 3 to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am migrating my project from rails 3 to rails 4, I have a lot of scopes but the scopes are written this way

```
scope :active, :conditions => {:active=>true}
```

While Rails 4.0 requires that scopes use a callable object such as a Proc or lambda this way

```
scope :active, -> { where active: true }
```

So, Is there a way to migrate without having to manually edit each and every scope in the code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're migrating to Rails 4.2, you can run:

```
rake rails:update
```

You can find more information in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-rake-task).

---

Otherwise, I'd try using [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop), with its `-a` flag which will automatically try to fix your code :-)

Comment: I played around with Rubocop after your recommendation and I really like it, thanks for mentioning it.